# Regex: how to keep all digits when splitting a string?

Tags: r, regex, text, split, strsplit

## Question

Using a regular expression, how do I keep all digits when splitting a string?

## Overview

I would like to split each element within the character vector `sample.text` into two elements: one of only digits and one of only the text.

## Current Attempt is Dropping Last Digit

This regular expression - `\\d\\s{1}` - inside of [`base::strsplit()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/strsplit) removes the last digit. Below is my attempt, along with my desired output.

```
# load necessary data -----
sample.text <-
  c("111110 Soybean Farming", "0116 Soybeans")

# split string by digit and one space pattern ------
strsplit(sample.text, split = "\\d\\s{1}")
# [[1]]
# [1] "11111"           "Soybean Farming"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "011"      "Soybeans"

# desired output --------
# [[1]]
# [1] "111110"           "Soybean Farming"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "0116"      "Soybeans"

# end of script #
```

Any advice on how I can split `sample.text` to keep all digits would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're splitting on `\\d`, the digit there is *consumed* in the regex, and not present in the output. Use lookbehind for a digit instead:

```
strsplit(sample.text, split = "(?<=\\d) ", perl=TRUE)
```

http://rextester.com/GDVFU71820

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your quick response and for showing me how to properly use look behinds in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternative solutions, using very simple pattern matching on the first occurrence of space:

**1) Indirectly by using `sub` to substitute your own delimiter, then `strsplit` on your delimiter:**

E.g. you can substitute ';' for the first space (if you know that character does not exist in your data):

```
strsplit( sub(' ', ';', sample.text), split=';')
```

**2) Using `regexpr` and `regmatches`**

You can effectively match on the first " " (space character), and split as follows:

```
regmatches(sample.text, regexpr(" ", sample.text), invert = TRUE)
```

Result is a list, if that's what you are after per your sample desired output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "111110"          "Soybean Farming"

[[2]]
[1] "0116"     "Soybeans"
```

**3) Using stringr library:**

```
library(stringr)
str_split_fixed(sample.text, " ", 2)  #outputs a character matrix

     [,1]     [,2]             
[1,] "111110" "Soybean Farming"
[2,] "0116"   "Soybeans"
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for showing me the usefulness of `sub()`, `regmatches()`/`regexpr()` and `str_split_fixed()`. I may end up taking advantage of that last one as I end up transforming that output into a 4 column `tibble` or `data.frame`. Appreciate your thoroughness!